# Hibernate saves new Elements in List without deleting old ones

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I have two objs; `Document` and `DocumentBatch`

*Document*

```
public class Document implements Serializable {

....
private String documentId;
private DocumentBatch documentBatch;
....}
```

*DocumentBatch*

```
public class DocumentBatch implements Serializable {


private String batchId;

private List<Document> lDocuments = new LinkedList<Document>();
....}
```

*Hibernate* mapping:

```
<class name="Document" table="DOCUMENTS">
  .....
  <id name="documentID" column="DOCUMENT_ID" type="string" />
  <many-to-one name="documentBatch" class="DocumentBatch" not-null="false" 
  cascade="save-update" lazy="false" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="BATCH_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
  ......
</class>


<class name="DocumentBatch" table="DOCUMENT_BATCHES">
     <id name="batchId" column="BATCH_ID" type="string" /> 
     <list name="lDocuments" table="DOCUMENTS" cascade="all"
        inverse="false" lazy="false" mutable="true">
        <key not-null="true">
            <column name="BATCH_ID" />
        </key>
        <list-index column="LIST_INDEX" base="0" />
        <one-to-many class="Document" />
       </list>
     ......
 </class>
```

`DocumentBatch` has a list of `Document`, everytime I run my testcase and use `session.saveOrUpdate(documentBatch)` to update `DocumentBatch` object with same primary key and but with NEW generated list of Document Object(all objects are new generated.).

Hibernate will update `DocumentBatch` with saving whole new list of documents with index but without deleting old elements of the list.

so when I run my testcase twice and everytime list of *Document* has 5 Obj, and I will have at last 10 objs.  two with index=0, two with index=1, etc.

So it doesn't update the list but only saves new one. The Elements of old list can be found in database. When I try to get `DocumentBatch, DocumentBatch` has a list of old objects.

How can I solve this problem? Where have made any mistakes?  Much thanks.

**update 1: UnitTestCase**

```
 @Test
public void testSaveDocumentBatch() throws Throwable {
....
String batchId = "500700";
DocumentBatch documentBatch = new DocumentBatch(batchId, name);
    ....
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String documentID = SessionIdentfierGenerator.nextSessionId();//generatting Id
    Document document = new Document(documentID);
    documentBatch.insertDocument(document);
}
    ....
    session.saveOrUpdate(documentBatch);
    ....}
```

And Methode insertDocument(Document document) in Class DocumentBatch:

```
public class DocumentBath{
.....
private List<Document> lDocuments = new LinkedList<Document>();
.....
public void insertDocument(Document document) {
    lDocuments.add(document); // lDocuments is a list DocumentBatch
    document.setDocumentBatch(this);
}
.....}
```

**Update 2: Oracle DB script:**

Of Document

```
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENTS(
DOCUMENT_ID VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
BATCH_ID VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
...);  


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_DOCUMENT ON DOCUMENTS (DOCUMENT_ID); 
ALTER TABLE DOCUMENTS ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_DOCUMENT PRIMARY KEY (DOCUMENT_ID) USING INDEX PK_DOCUMENT); 

ALTER TABLE DOCUMENTS ADD (CONSTRAINT FK_DOCUMENT_BATCH_ID FOREIGN KEY (BATCH_ID) REFERENCES DOCUMENT_BATCHES (BATCH_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Of DocumentBatch

```
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT_BATCHES(
BATCH_ID VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)     NOT NULL
...);

ALTER TABLE DOCUMENT_BATCHES ADD (
PRIMARY KEY (BATCH_ID));
```

Comment: Can you provide code where you are fetching or creating documentBatch before calling saveOrUpdate. Need to check if documentBatch object is fetched from DB or is it newly created everytime with same id??

Comment: Thanks of your quick reply.  I have just updated original post.

Comment: From a List obj in Class DocumentBatch -- private List<Document> lDocuments = new LinkedList<Document>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. In your test case, you are creating new entity object for entity which is already present in DB. This confuses hibernate & hibernate doesn't go for deleting existing documents.

```
String batchId = "500700";
    DocumentBatch documentBatch = new DocumentBatch(batchId, name);
```

Instead of this "new DocumentBatch(batchId, name)", first use get() or load() to fetch existing DocumentBatch object by id 500700. Once you fetch existing object, then do below steps.

1) Create a method e.g. clearExistingDocuments(). In this method first iterate over list of documents & make BATCH_ID null. Once iteration is done then remove all those documents from list.

2) Now add newly created documents in same empty list. Avoid creating new list instance. Use same empty list instance & add new documents.

THis should solve the issue. Due to these steps hibernate will have knowledge that initially there were some existing values & now those are explicitly removed, so hibernate will fire related removal queries. Also use orphan-delete if you want. THis will delete orphan DOcument object instead of keeping them in document table.

Comment: your answer works naturally. you know I can persuade Hibernate to believe that the new created DocumentBatch with Id 500700 is that DocumentBatch in DB, but without its List of Documents. So if someone just creates a new DocumentBatch without asking whether it exists already, then it will be unsafe.